# GCC allows arrays to be returned from function - bug or feature?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc

I was amazed to find out that GCC allows functions to return arrays when trailing return type is used instead of normal one. As you probably knows arrays can't be copied so this is quite limited but let me show you some cool [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/v5cCXzAKq5E1i69f).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

auto func() -> int [5]
{
    return {4, 56, 78, 4, 0};
}

int main()
{
    cout << func()[2] << endl;
    cout << typeid(func).name() << endl;
}
```

Is this a compiler bug or some new feature?

*Interestingly 'typeid' returns 'FA5_ivE' which is demangled as '`int (()) [5]`' and this means exactly what you think an function returning array of 5 int's.*

EDIT: I tried bounding the returned array into rvalue reference but without any success (used most of the possible forms):

```
auto &&refArrayTemp{ func() };
```

Seems that this extensions is rather useless.

Comment: I guess that the array is a `static const int[]` one... If that is the case, the compiler is behaving correctly.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch not so; I can write `func` taking `int` parameters and they are placed into the returned array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was a [bug in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65775) (fixed [as of 2017-07-03](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65775#c3)), caused by inconsistent treatment of trailing-return-types.

First note the difference in error message between two attempts to declare a function returning a function:

```
using Fv = void();
Fv f1();             // error: 'f1' declared as function returning a function
auto f2() -> Fv;     // error: function return type cannot be function
```

The first error comes from [`decl.c`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/dfec190b121ec95ea292155aff38e1330641a162/gcc/cp/decl.c#L9729), handling declarators, while the second is a lot deeper into the internals, from [`tree.c`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d2e9c25258679cb1ffb7a84588d458035c6d9c02/gcc/tree.c#L8128), attempting to build the function type preparatory to generating code.

Trailing-return-types are handled in decl.c [30 lines below](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/dfec190b121ec95ea292155aff38e1330641a162/gcc/cp/decl.c#L9759) the above error - too late to catch it with the above error code, and it is not handled separately.

With arrays, similarly using a trailing-return-type allows us to skip the checks in `decl.c`, the difference being that function-returning-array is actually valid in terms of gcc's internal representation.

Note that you can't do much with it; gcc doesn't allow you to assign, reference-bind, decay or pass the result of `func()` to another function:

```
auto a1 = func();
// error: invalid use of non-lvalue array

auto& a2 = func();
// error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int (&)[5]' from an rvalue of type 'int [5]'

auto&& a3 = func();
// error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
```

Indeed, even your code is rejected at `-Wpedantic`:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids subscripting non-lvalue array
```

Finally, by exploiting a similar bug (qualifiers are stripped from scalars before handling of trailing-return-types) we can create a function with type `int const volatile()`:

```
int const volatile g1();          // warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
auto g2() -> int const volatile;  // OK!!
```

Comment: Please don't fix this. Rather allow array operations. It would be very nice if you do. Like array copying by value and bounding to 'rvalue' references. No compatibility will be lost and I don't think it will be very hard to make but it will easy our lives.

Comment: @FISOCPP You already can. `std::array` is way better than a built-in C-style array.

Comment: But why not allow both? Bult-in arrays looks a lot more cool.

Comment: @FISOCPP I agree that it would be great to allow this. However to do so would make the language inconsistent either with C or with itself, so is unlikely to succeed. You could ask on the std-proposals group, but I fear that you would get short shrift there either.

Comment: @FISOCPP, I would be inclined to go the other way. I would like to ban C-arrays, and then in a few years we could reintroduce the `[`. For example, it would be nice if `int x[5]` actually declared an `std::array`. And the abominable behavoiur of arrays in function parameter lists needs to change :)

Comment: @FISOCPP Oh no you didn't! The "decay to pointer and forget the size" is the most terrible thing in the world. Use `std::array` everywhere. It's the thing you _should_ use if you don't hate yourself.

Answer (score 8):

Latest draft, [dcl.array]/p10:

> **Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function, although they may have a return type of
>   type pointer or reference to such things.** There shall be no arrays of functions, although there can be arrays
>   of pointers to functions.

This could be a non-standard GCC extension. [It doesn't compile in the trunk version of clang.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2xHCowlDxFLloiRz) However, this may also be a bug since it has inconsistent behavior with a [non-trailing return type](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LlLyrcaaoML1P5nv).

Comment: So, what? I mean, we did know it was not legal and could either be a bug or some sort of extension.

Comment: @black What are you referring to?